# ActionMailer and Ramaze

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ramaze

Is it possible to use ActionMailer in a web framework like Ramaze, or do I need to use Rails?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use ActionMailer without Rails quite easily. I'm not familiar with Ramaze, but here's plain ruby, which should be easy to integrate into whatever framework you wish:

**PATH/mailer.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'action_mailer'

class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def my_email
    recipients "recipient@their_domain.com"
    from       "me@my_domain.com"
    subject    "my subject"

    body        :variable1 => 'a', :variable2 => 'b'
  end
end

Mailer.template_root = File.dirname(__FILE__)
Mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
Mailer.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

# this sends the email
Mailer.deliver_my_email
```

Then put the email templates in a directory named after the your ActionMailer class

**PATH/mailer/my_email.html.erb**

```
variable 1: <%= @variable1 %>
variable 2: <%= @variable2 %>
```

Check out the [API Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) for more configuration options, but those are the basics

Comment: I've answered a question about how to do this in rails 3 as it's quite different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951310/actionmailer-3-without-rails/4951506#4951506