# Issue with template path inside of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Error message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
Missing template gem_name/exception_mailer/exception_report with "mailer". 
Searched in:
         * "gem_name/exception_mailer"
```

This is my folder structure:

```
lib/
  gem_name/
    exception_mailer.rb  # extends ActionMailer::Base
    exception_mailer/
      exception_report.html.erb
  gem_name.rb
```

I can not think of why my template is not being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I needed to modify my view paths array.

```
ActionMailer::Base.view_paths = ...
```

or

```
prepend_view_path('path')
```

Links:

- [ActionMailer 3 without rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951310/actionmailer-3-without-rails)
- [Using ActionMailer Without Rails](http://excid3.com/blog/using-actionmailer-without-rails/)