# Rails: Send email from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I am creating a gem, to send notitifications

Notifications are sent to user using his email address, so to send notification am going to send text-email to user.

So how to send email from gem? as I need to inherit the class from `Actionmailer::Base`

```
Module ABC
  class notify < ActionMailer::Base
    def send_mail
    end
  end
end
```

Do I need to add any gem in my gemspec file? `rails` or `actionmailer` gem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `ActionMailer` is self sufficient and perfect for the task. Why do you want to create a gem?

Comment: Its a notification to 3rd party, and am sending notification to them.. so want to send email them, hence adding gem for internal purpose.. It would be helpful if you can help me to solve this doubt

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot understand your motive behind creating a gem. I would however have done something like this:
Create app/model/notify.rb

```
class notify < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "notify@example.com", :content_type => "text/html"
  def send_mail(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Notification mail from xyz")
  end
end
```

Now create a mailer view app/views/notify/send_mail.erb

```
Hi @user.name,
Here is your notification.
Thanks
```

This can now be called from anywhere in your code. All you have to do is:

```
Notify.send_mail(user).deliver
```

You can keep on adding different methods and their template view and send them as

```
Notify.your_method(user).deliver
```

Comment: Tried this, but getting error
uninitialized constant ABC::ActionMailer (NameError)
its not getting from where to refer ActionMailer
(ABC is my module name).. do we need to add any depedency in gemspec?

Comment: have you configured your actionmailer in config/application.rb?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any config-folder in my gem structure.. all I have is lib folder, gemspec, gemfile etc.

Comment: read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views

Comment: found a partial solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951310/actionmailer-3-without-rails need to dig in more.. @shivam Thanks for help